# Issue with CASE statement in a calculated column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `SELECT` statement which works fine up until the `CASE` part, I think it's just a case of syntax error and the `lead time` bit. I am using Oracle APEX.

I get the error;

`ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

```
select 
 supplier.companyname as "Supplier", 
 purchaseorder.orderdate as "Order Date", 
 purchaseorder.duedate as "Due Date", 
 popayment.datedelivered as "Delivered", 
 (popayment.paymentdate - popayment.datedelivered) - 31 as paidontime,

/* this is the same as the next one (this works fine) */
(popayment.datedelivered - purchaseorder.duedate) - 1 as deleiverylate,   

 /* trying to advance the previous query (this does not work) */
 popayment.datedelivered - purchaseorder.duedate -1, 
                           case when "lead time" <0 then 'early'
                                when "lead time" >0 then 'late'
                                else 'on time'
                           end as "lead time";


from supplier, purchaseorder, suppliercontact, popayment


where 
     purchaseorder.SUPPLIERCONTACTID2 = suppliercontact.suppliercontactid
and
     supplier.supplierid = suppliercontact.supplierid
and
    purchaseorder.purchaseorderid = popayment.purchaseorderid

order by COMPANYNAME
```

Thanks for any help
Dangerous Brian

Comment: Why do you have a semicolon after "lead time" ? That should not be there. (And not related to the error, but why aren't you using ANSI-style joins?)

Comment: @DangerousTreacle could you explain the field `lead time` in `case when "lead time" <0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT supplier.companyname                              AS "Supplier",
  purchaseorder.orderdate                                AS "Order Date",
  purchaseorder.duedate                                  AS "Due Date",
  popayment.datedelivered                                AS "Delivered",
  (popayment.paymentdate - popayment.datedelivered) - 31 AS paidontime,
  /* this is the same as the next one (this works fine) */
  (popayment.datedelivered - purchaseorder.duedate) - 1 AS deleiverylate,
  /* trying to advance the previous query (this does not work) */
  CASE
    WHEN popayment.datedelivered - purchaseorder.duedate -1 <0
    THEN 'early'
    WHEN popayment.datedelivered - purchaseorder.duedate -1 >0
    THEN 'late'
    ELSE 'on time'
  END AS "lead time"
FROM supplier,
  purchaseorder,
  suppliercontact,
  popayment
WHERE purchaseorder.SUPPLIERCONTACTID2 = suppliercontact.suppliercontactid
AND supplier.supplierid                = suppliercontact.supplierid
AND purchaseorder.purchaseorderid      = popayment.purchaseorderid
ORDER BY COMPANYNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You should delete `;` at  `end as "lead time";`

Comment: ok I deleted the `;` and get this error `ORA-00904: "lead time": invalid identifier`

Comment: `lead time` is not an actual column it me trying to calculate two others to make `lead time`

Comment: @DangerousTreacle - do any of your tables have a column called `"lead time"` - as a lower-case quoted identifier? If not you're trying to refer to the alias you've giving the case expression *within itself*. You can't refer to a column alias in the same level of query anyway, but it doesn't make sense where you've used it?

Comment: no I'm trying to calculate 2 columns to make a `lead time` column in the results

Comment: @DangerousTreacle could you explain the field `lead time` in `case when "lead time" <0` ?

Comment: that worked a treat thank you very much, I'll accept in 3 mins

Comment: it tells me if a delivery is on time, early or late

Comment: Is there a way to get the results of the query into Excel?, I'm using Oracle APEX online. Tried looking and it's something to do with the utilities but not sure how.

Comment: it's ok I found it out